# Behaviour of weights in glmmTMB

Tags: r, lme4, weighted, glmmtmb

I have some troubles in understanding the behaviour of weights in glmmTMB as it leads to not comparable results with lmer.

This example could help to understand the problem:

```
m9a <- lmer(wi_gamma ~ level + (1 | TAG_IDc), weights=sub$pesi, data=sub)  
m9b <- lmer(wi_gamma ~ level + (1 | TAG_IDc), weights=sub$pesi/max(sub$pesi), data=sub)
```

These two models give identical results, thus I suppose lmer scale weights to one.

Whit TMB:

```
m9c <- glmmTMB(wi_gamma ~ level + (1 | TAG_IDc), weights=sub$pesi, data=sub)
```

The output is similar to m9a, but I suspect this can be by chance because we tried other models and that was not always the case

```
m9d <- glmmTMB(wi_gamma ~ level + (1 | TAG_IDc), weights=sub$pesi/max(sub$pesi), data=sub)
```

This is completely different from m9c and also m9b. We can't figure out why...

I attach a dataset in case someone can help.

```
   wi_gamma level           TAG_IDc
1   1.0697674     3       i_16334_ALT
2   1.3043478     3       i_16336_ALT
3   1.4754098     3       i_16344_ALT
4   1.2592593     3       i_16350_ALT
5   1.0344828     3       i_16351_ALT
6   0.6422018     3       i_16355_ALT
7   0.9583333     3       i_16356_ALT
8   1.3129771     3       i_16363_ALT
9   0.4203152     3       i_16373_ALT
10  1.0714286     3      i_16438A_ALT
11  1.0576923     3       i_16490_ALT
12  0.9236234     3       i_16509_ALT
13  1.0210210     3       i_16523_ALT
14  0.9677419     3       i_16527_ALT
15  0.9181637     3       i_16564_ALT
16  1.4261745     3       i_16566_ALT
17  1.0242588     3       i_16579_ALT
18  1.3157895     3       i_16588_ALT
19  1.2761506     3       i_16680_ALT
20  1.5660685     3       i_16684_ALT
21  0.8371385     3       i_16685_ALT
22  3.3333333     3       i_17004_ALT
23  0.5693950     3 i_16318_CAPODARSO
24  0.5573770     3 i_16333_CAPODARSO
25  0.3292181     3 i_16343_CAPODARSO
26  0.1683502     3 i_16353_CAPODARSO
27  0.7380074     3 i_16357_CAPODARSO
28  0.6269592     3 i_16358_CAPODARSO
29  0.3125000     3 i_16364_CAPODARSO
30  0.3278689     3 i_16379_CAPODARSO
31  0.4575163     3      i_pic12_gela
32  0.6463878     3      i_pic13_gela
33  0.3048780     3      i_pic15_gela
34  0.2222222     3      i_pic16_gela
35  0.2811245     3      i_pic18_gela
36  0.3083700     3      i_pic19_gela
37  1.3274336     3       i_16191_GRA
38  1.0884354     3       i_16328_GRA
39  0.9302326     3       i_16340_GRA
40  1.1111111     3       i_16360_GRA
41  1.6853933     3       i_16361_GRA
42  1.3227513     3       i_16362_GRA
43  2.2660099     3       i_16365_GRA
44  0.6621005     3       i_16371_GRA
45  1.0185185     3       i_16375_GRA
46  1.5909091     3       i_16377_GRA
47  0.8737864     3       i_16438_GRA
48  2.3090278     3       i_16479_GRA
49  0.6951872     3       i_16520_GRA
50  1.1654135     3       i_16550_GRA
51  0.6250000     3       i_16558_GRA
52  1.0619469     3      i_16673A_GRA
53  2.0068027     3       i_17001_GRA
54  1.3461538     3       i_40401_MAT
55  1.1764706     3       i_40432_MAT
56  0.0010000     3       i_40441_MAT
57  1.8181818     3       i_40442_MAT
58  0.5494505     3       i_40449_MAT
59  0.4651163     3       i_40450_MAT
60  1.3636364     3       i_40468_MAT
61  3.0136986     3       i_40472_MAT
62  1.8918919     3       i_40475_MAT
63  0.2127660     3       i_40508_MAT
64  2.0000000     3       i_40514_MAT
65  2.7058824     3 i_41380_TARQUINIA
66  1.9780220     3 i_41397_TARQUINIA
67  0.9876543     3 i_41399_TARQUINIA
68  1.2941176     3 i_41429_TARQUINIA
69  1.2745098     3 i_41436_TARQUINIA
70  0.4444444     3 i_41469_TARQUINIA
71  2.9026193     2       i_16191_GRA
72  0.8282671     2 i_16318_CAPODARSO
73  1.4331228     2       i_16328_GRA
74  0.8658397     2 i_16333_CAPODARSO
75  1.6631572     2       i_16334_ALT
76  2.0049406     2       i_16336_ALT
77  0.7523895     2       i_16340_GRA
78  0.4074540     2 i_16343_CAPODARSO
79  1.0833450     2       i_16344_ALT
80  1.8238924     2       i_16350_ALT
81  1.7721126     2       i_16351_ALT
82  0.2646174     2 i_16353_CAPODARSO
83  0.6909334     2       i_16355_ALT
84  1.5339254     2       i_16356_ALT
85  1.1015470     2 i_16357_CAPODARSO
86  1.0525894     2 i_16358_CAPODARSO
87  1.9734806     2       i_16360_GRA
88  0.9523918     2       i_16361_GRA
89  1.4169294     2       i_16362_GRA
90  1.6450794     2       i_16363_ALT
91  0.1894661     2 i_16364_CAPODARSO
92  5.1850062     2       i_16365_GRA
93  1.1319997     2       i_16371_GRA
94  0.6967395     2       i_16373_ALT
95  1.1435281     2       i_16375_GRA
96  0.7470534     2       i_16377_GRA
97  0.4281720     2 i_16379_CAPODARSO
98  1.7035234     2       i_16438_GRA
99  1.7459570     2      i_16438A_ALT
100 5.5133775     2       i_16479_GRA
101 1.5966948     2       i_16490_ALT
102 1.4920488     2       i_16509_ALT
103 0.7903890     2       i_16520_GRA
104 0.7804563     2       i_16523_ALT
105 1.3696917     2       i_16527_ALT
106 3.0779570     2       i_16550_GRA
107 0.3343953     2       i_16558_GRA
108 1.3276080     2       i_16564_ALT
109 2.0664791     2       i_16566_ALT
110 1.5499096     2       i_16579_ALT
111 2.0303196     2       i_16588_ALT
112 1.7798461     2      i_16673A_GRA
113 1.3379980     2       i_16680_ALT
114 2.6767394     2       i_16684_ALT
115 1.1750567     2       i_16685_ALT
116 3.5022469     2       i_17001_GRA
117 2.3362075     2       i_17004_ALT
118 1.4023931     2       i_40401_MAT
119 1.1088690     2       i_40432_MAT
120 0.0010000     2       i_40441_MAT
121 2.6989452     2       i_40442_MAT
122 0.9312767     2       i_40449_MAT
123 0.3017808     2       i_40450_MAT
124 1.5893789     2       i_40468_MAT
125 2.9138612     2       i_40472_MAT
126 3.8217888     2       i_40475_MAT
127 0.1440525     2       i_40508_MAT
128 5.3833800     2       i_40514_MAT
129 3.7664419     2 i_41380_TARQUINIA
130 3.0025754     2 i_41397_TARQUINIA
131 2.6042539     2 i_41399_TARQUINIA
132 2.2046273     2 i_41429_TARQUINIA
133 1.8770580     2 i_41436_TARQUINIA
134 0.7418886     2 i_41469_TARQUINIA
135 0.6431548     2      i_pic12_gela
136 0.9083064     2      i_pic13_gela
137 0.6377614     2      i_pic15_gela
138 0.0704814     2      i_pic16_gela
139 1.5867438     2      i_pic18_gela
140 1.8477214     2      i_pic19_gela
```

Comment: Maybe [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/285#issue-285487095) helps.